# JAVA TCP client not printing and disconnecting

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server and client, but the client never prints the last system.out and disconnects from server socket.

My client message loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(args[2]); i++) {
    long messageTimeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    outToServer.write(MSG.getBytes());
    outToServer.flush();

    Thread.sleep((long) messageTimePerSecond);
    long messageTimeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalMessageTime = messageTimeEnd - messageTimeStart; //Meassure total packet transfer time.
    System.out.println("Message " + i + ": '" + MSG + "' sent in: " + totalMessageTime);

    elapsedTime += totalMessageTime;
}

while (true) {
    try {
        int msgLength = serverEcho.read(buf);
        if (msgLength == -1) {
            break;
        }
        String echoMessage = new String(buf);
        System.out.println("ECHO MESSAGE: " + echoMessage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Hot damn");
    }
}

System.out.printf(args[2] + " Messages sent in: " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
outToServer.close();
serverEcho.close();
socket.close();
```

It never gets to the four last lines for some reason. And I have no Idea why.

If it matters, here is my Server class run method:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                inFromClient = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                outToClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                //InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                //DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
                int msgLength = 0;

                msgLength = inFromClient.read(dataBuffer);

                String message = new String(dataBuffer);
                System.out.println("Message recieved: " + message);

                outToClient.write(message.getBytes(), 0, msgLength);
                outToClient.flush();
                System.out.println("Echo message sent: " + message);

            } catch (SocketException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated by client.");
                break;
            }
        }

        clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: " + clientSocket.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("Client thread terminated.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never leaving the `while(true)` loop because you're never getting `serverEcho.read(buf);` to return you `-1`.

Comment: I might be brainfarting hard right now, but I can't figure out how to exit the while loop at all. I set it to a boolean variable, while(b) and then I thought of having a check inside and set it to false to exit, but what can I check to set it to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know the amount of data that the server will return to you since the server is returning the same information that the client is sending to him.

Therefore, you could try this approach:

**Server**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    DataInputStream inFromClient = null;
    DataOutputStream outToClient = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4321);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port 4321. Cause: " + ioe);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("#Server#listening on port 4321!");

    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Accept failed on port: 4321. Cause: " + ioe);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("#Server#accepting connections on port 4321!");

    try {
        inFromClient = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        outToClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Input and output streams creation failed. Cause: " + ioe);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("#Server#created input and output streams!");

    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];

    try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                int msgLength = 0;

                msgLength = inFromClient.read(dataBuffer);

                String message = new String(dataBuffer);
                System.out.println("Message recieved: " + message);

                outToClient.write(message.getBytes(), 0, msgLength);
                outToClient.flush();
                System.out.println("Echo message sent: " + message);

            } catch (SocketException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated by client.");
                break;
            }
        }

        clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: " + clientSocket.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("Client thread terminated.");
    } finally {
        try {
            outToClient.close();
            inFromClient.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Unable to close streams and sockets. Cause: " + ioe);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    String MSG = "Hello from client, mister server!";
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
    DataInputStream inFromServer = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 4321);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Unable to connect with host: localhost. Cause: " + ioe);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("@Client@connected with server localhost on port 4321!");

    try {
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        inFromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Input and output streams creation failed. Cause: " + ioe);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("@Client@created input and output streams!");

    long messageTimePerSecond = 3000;
    long elapsedTime = 0;

    try {
        for (int it = 0; it < 5; it++) {
            long messageTimeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

            outToServer.write(MSG.getBytes());
            outToServer.flush();

            Thread.sleep((long) messageTimePerSecond);
            long messageTimeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // Measure total packet transfer time.
            long totalMessageTime = messageTimeEnd - messageTimeStart;
            System.out.println("Message " + it + ": '" + MSG + "' sent in: " + totalMessageTime);

            elapsedTime += totalMessageTime;
        }

        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
        String echoMessage = "";
        int msgLength = 0;
        int totalData = MSG.length();
        boolean finish = false;

        while (!finish) {
            try {
                msgLength = inFromServer.read(dataBuffer);
                echoMessage += new String(dataBuffer, 0, msgLength);

                if (echoMessage.length() == totalData) {
                    finish = true;
                }

                System.out.println("ECHO MESSAGE: " + echoMessage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Hot damn");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Something bad happened. Cause: " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    } finally {
        System.out.printf("5 Messages sent in: " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
        try {
            inFromServer.close();
            outToServer.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Unable to close streams and socket. Cause: " + ioe);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Both *Server* and *Client* implement `Runnable` and your main class can be like this:

```
public class ClientServerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread server = new Thread(new Server());
        server.start();
        Thread client = new Thread(new Client());
        client.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaaah, Of course! This solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: However, there is one thing, When I get the echo, It skips the first Letter of the message. (the "A" is not at the beginning, but is appended last.)

Comment: According to your server `sysouts`, is it receiving and sending the data in the right order?

Comment: Yes, it receives it exactly as it should.

Comment: And is the server sending it as it should? What are the contents of `MSG`?

Comment: Yes, the server simply returns the message the same way it was received.
However I could not use your "echoMessage += new String(buf, 0, msgLength);" and had to remove the offset and length, because when run it threw an out of bound exception.

Comment: What's the `buf` size and what's your input `MSG`?

Comment: I tried using buffsize = 1 and the message is 20. It sends and recieves fine when i don't use offset and length, but maybe that could be the issue?

Comment: If you use `byte[] buf = new byte[1]`, when you do `serverEcho.read(buf);`, you'll only read 1 byte of data. In order for your to use offset and lenght, you have to have your `buf` with, at least, the size of the message sent by the server. Which in this case is 20. Try setting your buffer with size 40, for instance, which means you can receive 40 bytes on your buffer, allowing you to receive your 20 byte message.

Comment: After trying 1,2,3,4 and 5 as buffer size in the client, the buffer size is somehow the offset, so having 1 as buffer means that the first character is for some reason skipped. using a buffersize of 3 makes the program spaz out and prints thousands and thousands of messages. (I have absolutely no idea why).
Using 20 as buffer means that the Echo message i get back is empty.

Comment: What's the type of input stream you're using?

Comment: Normal "OutputStream" and "InputStream".
I just realized why it skips the first letter. I test send a message once before the actual send. That's why. I test to see the transfer time and use it as a modifier for the time the program should wait (Thread.sleep). I feel so dumb now.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: The problem still remains with the thread arrayindex out of bounds exception though for write(Byte[], off, length). Strange

Comment: What's the size of your server's `dataBuffer`?

Comment: The server buffer was set to 1024. (Hard set)

Comment: @Danny, I've updated my answer with a full working code. Please refer it in order to solve your problem.